# Tail behavior of a very complicated function near the origin

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

First some preliminary definitions.

We say that a probability density function (pdf) $h$ is zero near the origin if
there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $h(u) = 0$ for all $u \in
(0,\delta)$.  Similarly, we say that $h$ is strictly positive near the origin if there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $h(u) > 0$ for all $u
\in (0,\delta)$.

Let $\mathbb{R}_+ = (0, \infty)$. If $h$ is positive near the origin and there exists a $c > -1$ such
that
$$\lim_{u\to 0} \frac{h(u)}{u^c} \in \mathbb{R}_+ \;,$$
then we say that $h$ is polynomial near the origin with power 
$c$.

Finally, if $h$ is positive near the origin and, for every $c > 0$, there
exists an $\eta_c > 0$ such that the ratio $\frac{h(u)}{u^c}$ is
strictly increasing in $(0,\eta_c)$, then we say that $h$ is
faster than polynomial near the origin.

I'm trying to determine if a certain pdf is either zero near the origin, polynomial near the origin, or faster than polynomial near the origin. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. The pdf under consideration is
$$h(u) = \frac{1}{u^2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-2\delta}{k} \frac{k+\delta}{B(\delta, \delta)} \exp\left\{ -\frac{(k+\delta)^2}{2u} \right\} I_{\mathbb{R}_+}(u) \;,$$
where $B(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the beta function given by $B(x,y) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ for $x,y > 0$, $\delta > 0$, and  $\binom{-2\delta}{k}:= (-1)^k \frac{\Gamma(k+2\delta)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(2\delta)}$.